# Position MediaController with setAnchorView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mediaplayer

I have a MediaController and i want it's position in top right screen,i use method SetAnchorView() follows
**My layout**

```
<RelativeLayout

    android:id="@+id/content_media"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
   <VideoView

       android:id="@+id/audio_play"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**and MyMediaController**

```
 VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.audio_play);
 MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
 mc.setMediaPlayer(this);
 mc.setAnchorView(video);
```

But my MediaController has displayed in top center screen.Plese help me.Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can try by setting

```
 mc.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0); //0's are just placeholders here
```

but **not** 0 values - **try setting the values in dp to what you want in the above method**. If that doesnt work as intended try setting the anchorview in the onPreparedListener once the size of the video is known.

```
video.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new OnVideoSizeChangedListener() { 
                                                @Override
                                                public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
                                                        /*
                                                         *  add media controller
                                                         */

                                                        mc.setAnchorView(video);
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }
                                        });
```

**EDIT UPDATE:** Turns out I solved a similar problem I had by extending the controller to make my own controller like this

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.MediaController;

public class CustomController extends MediaController {
       public CustomController(Context context, View anchor)     {
          super(context);   
          super.setAnchorView(anchor);  
       }    
      @Override  
       public void setAnchorView(View view)     {  
           // Do nothing   
      } 
    }
```

Now just do this in your activity - this works for me

```
        CustomController mc = new CustomController(this, mVideoView);
        mc.setMediaPlayer(video);
        mc.setAnchorView(video);
        video.setMediaController(mc);
```

Comment: But i want to set margin of controller with screen,and i don't know how to set it,my Videoview display in top right screen but my mediacontroller not display below VideoView,it display in center :D

Comment: Can i have your email address?,i will give you my application,help me to fix it,thanks you :D

Comment: @user1797447 don't expect people come here to do your work because no one will do it just saying

Comment: Nothing to it.  Just create a new media controller class like I ve shown above and modify your activity.  You can give me a pastebin link I could look at and I can tell you where to put it